# .htaccess file RewriteRule is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Chrome.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Safari.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Netscape Navigator.*
RewriteRule .* /igra/ [L,R=301]
```

It should show to user for those three web browsers (chrome, safari,netscape) web pages locate
in golder /igra/ , but it says 500 error like below:

Internal Server Error
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting 500 due to presence of a space in `Netscape Navigator`

Try this more compact rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(Chrome|Safari|Netscape Navigator)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!igra/).*)$ /igra/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I put same thing you wrote and still there is problem. Chrome says: The webpage at http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Learn more about this problem.
Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS     This webpage has a redirect loop       Any idea why this is happening?   In line only stay http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/   there is no file ....

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put a condition. Just fixed it, try it now.

Comment: Are you sure? I have tested it and it is working. Do you have some other rules also? Place this rule on top and if it still facing problem then post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I put exaclly the same thing you wrote above. I try it few times and nothing... It seems like it says "Oh yeah file you looking for is in folder /igra" and than do nothing -something like if you want then something should be done to go there....

Comment: Is `/igra/` a directory? Is there any .htaccess inside it? Do you have any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: btw I just tested `http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/` from Safari and it didn't even add `/igra/` in the URL.

Comment: /igra is directory no .htaccess in it I'm not sure for cms/php I'm not using it but webhosting should have it install. Below is what I reacive:  

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/korisnik.html  and where it should go http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/korisnik.html you can try in chrome or safari and it want work (other will work normally) ....

Comment: It still not working. Iput your code exaclly the same. YOu can try in safari and chrome won't work at all. Other browsers will work normal....

Comment: Actually it worked fine for me. `http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/korisnik.html` in chrome browser became `http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/korisnik.html` You need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: You are genius! Do you know why is this happening? If someone comes to my website few times will it start making problems for him because of browser cache - how it is related to .htaccess file? I was thinking Apache in my web host sever is the one that decide what to send to web page visitor?

Comment: As long as you're using 301 you should be fine. Also can you mark the answer as accepted now?

Comment: Do you know how to make it that browser not show to visitor that page is taken from another location?     http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/korisnik.html not http://aluminijumskicamci.co.rs/igra/korisnik.html  I don't want to see it's from directory /igra?

Comment: Sure just change flags to `[L,NC]` (remove R=301)